# Noda Time Countdown

Tags: c#, countdown, nodatime

I have written an application to show the remaining time until the next big industry trade-show.
(it's about two years in the future at the time of writing)

I started off using the standard [`DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) class but quickly ran into issues dealing with the varying number of days in each month, 2016 is a Leap Year and contains a [Leap Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/February_29), Daylight Savings Time, etc.

Thankfully I discovered [**NodaTime**](http://nodatime.org/). (Thanks @JonSkeet)

Not so thankfully, the way I am used to working with DateTime doesn't apply and I'm having a really hard time figuring out how to get the time remaining. (There aren't many examples floating around)

For example, the following code doesn't work because you can't subtract an [instant](http://nodatime.org/1.3.x/api/html/AllMembers_T_NodaTime_Instant.htm) from a [LocalDateTime](http://nodatime.org/1.3.x/api/html/T_NodaTime_LocalDateTime.htm):

```c#
void example()
{
    DateTime DT = Convert.ToDateTime("09/12/2016 10:00AM");

    LocalDateTime NodaLocalDateTime = new LocalDateTime(
        DT.Year, DT.Month, DT.Day, DT.Hour, DT.Minute, 0);

        Period P = NodaLocalDateTime - SystemClock.Instance.Now;
}
```

So the question becomes:

### How do you get the remaining time from now until some date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To determine a "calendrical" amount of time between two events, you want `Period` as you've already discovered. However, that *only* deals with local dates and times.

To determine a "calendar-neutral" amount of time between two events, you can use `Instant` and `Duration` - but then you can't display the number of months left.

Both of these approaches have drawbacks, but basically they're fundamental to the way that time works. If you use the local time approach, then you'll find that the amount of time will jump back or forward an hour as you go over a DST transition. If you use the instant approach, you're restricted to days/months/hours/minutes etc - not months.

One option for between the two would be to use `LocalDateTime` and `Period`, but anchor both the event and the current time in UTC. That way there'll never be a discontinuity, as UTC is an unchanging base line, effectively. This also means that you'll always display the same amount of "time left" regardless of where in the world you look at the counter (or host the code, depending on exactly what you were planning to do).

If you want more details about *why* you can't get a `Period` between two `ZonedDateTime` values, I could think of examples which are fundamentally problematic. The bottom line is that calendrical arithmetic and time zones don't play nicely together though...

Just to give some actual code, I would have something like:

```
public sealed class EventCountdown
{
     private readonly LocalDateTime eventTimeUtc;
     private readonly IClock clock;

     // It's probably most convenient to express the event time with the time zone
     // in which it occurs. You could easily change this though.
     public EventCountdown(ZonedDateTime zonedEventTime, IClock clock)
     {
         this.eventTimeUtc = zonedEventTime.WithZone(DateTimeZone.Utc).LocalDateTime;
         this.clock = clock;
     }

     public Period GetPeriodRemaining()
     {
         return Period.Between(clock.Now.InUtc().LocalDateTime, eventTimeUtc);
     }
}
```

Note that in Noda Time 2.0 the `IClock.Now` property is being changed to a `GetCurrentInstant` method... but in that case you'd probably use a `ZonedClock` in UTC and call `GetCurrentLocalDateTime` on it.

Comment: Sure enough it works. It just feels strange to be messing about with `OffsetDateTime` and `ZonedDateTime` when this compromise is essentially stripping the offset & timezone (comparing just UTC values). Is there no solution where the difference in timezone UTC offsets can be applied to the Period(.Between)?

Comment: @Okuma.Scott: I'm not sure what you mean, I'm afraid - but this solution *is* just comparing UTC values... and it's reasonably easy to do. Note that this code doesn't use `OffsetDateTime` - it goes straight from `ZonedDateTime` to `LocalDateTime`.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I ended up using is [`Period.Between()`](http://nodatime.org/1.3.x/api/html/M_NodaTime_Period_Between_2.htm), which seems do the trick.

```c#
using NodaTime;

    DateTime EventDT;
    LocalDateTime LocalizedEventDT;
    Period TimeLeft; 

    public EventCountdown()
    {
        // Start with a date and time
        EventDT = Convert.ToDateTime("09/12/2016 10:00AM");

        // Localize it
        LocalizedEventDT = new LocalDateTime(
            EventDT.Year, EventDT.Month, 
            EventDT.Day, EventDT.Hour, 
            EventDT.Minute, 0);
    }

    // find out how much time is between now and the future date
    public Period GetPeriodRemaining()
    {
        DateTime dt_Now = DateTime.Now;

        return Period.Between(new LocalDateTime(
            dt_Now.Year, dt_Now.Month, dt_Now.Day, dt_Now.Hour, 
            dt_Now.Minute, dt_Now.Second), LocalizedEventDT);
    }
```

[image: the result]

---

If anyone has a solution that does this while taking time zones (local vs where the event is taking place) into account that would be awesome. (I tried doing this using a [`ZonedDateTime`](http://nodatime.org/1.3.x/api/html/AllMembers_T_NodaTime_ZonedDateTime.htm) in a similar fashion but ran into a brick wall).

Also, it's not clear to me if this method is taking the various days of the month, daylight savings time, leap year, etc. into account. Anyone know?
If it is not, obviously I'd welcome any solutions that do so gracefully.

Comment: Once you start including a time zone, it's not at all obvious what the answer should be. Arithmetic goes squiffy, basically. You can find the "absolute" time left, which you could represent in fixed-length units such as hours or days (if you assume a day is 24 hours) but the number of *months* isn't always obvious. Note that `LocalDateTime.FromDateTime` is your friend, by the way...